# Advice in making define function out of existing code in Python

Tags: python

I have just begun taking a Python coding class, using IDLE, and looking for some guidance. I am writing a program to determine if a user inputted value is a prime number or not a prime number. so far I have written the following code:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if x == 2:
     print(x, 'is a prime number')
if x>1:
     for y in range (2, x):
          if (x % y)==0:
               print (x, 'is not a prime number')
               break
          else:
               print (x, 'is a prime number')
               break
else:
     print(x, 'is not a prime number')
```

I am required to use the 'def' function for this program.
According to instructions, this is how the code should be presented:

```
def isPrime(testnumber):
#insert function codes to test if the number is prime
num = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
if isPrime(num):
     print("{0} is a prime number".format(num))
else:
     print("{0} is not a prime number".format(num))
```

However i cannot work out how to include the code to determine a prime number as a 'def' and execute the above.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Regards, Liam.

Comment: Your `def isPrime` would have all the code in your first snippet, but indented one level.  You'll want that code to return something, and not just print and break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, when checking for primes, you only have to look as far as sqrt(x).  You don't have to go all the way to x.  I haven't fixed that here.

```
def isPrime(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    if x>1:
        for y in range (2, x):
            if (x % y) == 0:
                 return False
        return True
    else:
        return False

num = int(input("Enter a number: ")) 
if isPrime(num):
     print("{0} is a prime number".format(num))
else:
     print("{0} is not a prime number".format(num))
```